# After Ctrl+P all fxHide directives fire disregarding the viewport size

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular10, angular13

On Angular 10 with Material Design.

In an open view on a large viewport, clicking Ctrl+P and closing the print window will hide all elements with fxHide directives.

This started about a week ago (don't no if that's relevant). Anyone else experienced this?

All fxHide directives fire disregarding the viewport size which means the top button will show but the lower button will not show. ANY element on the page with the fxHide directive will hide.

```
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="showFilterDialog('payments')">
                <mat-icon aria-label="Filter"
                          matTooltip="Filter"
                          class="text-grey">
                    filter_list
                </mat-icon>
            </button>
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="onExport()" fxHide.xs> <!-- This will hide! -->
                <mat-icon aria-label="Export payments"
                          matTooltip="Export"
                          class="text-grey">
                    cloud_download
                </mat-icon>
            </button>
```

Edit: I have seen this in Angular 13 again!

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1201) for this. And [another one](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1228)

Comment: Thx @MichaelDoye "My Google skills weak they are..."

Answer (score 2):

Temporary fix according to https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1201#issuecomment-608468692

Add this to your module(s) containing `import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';`

(Remember to import `MediaMarshaller`)

```
export class PaymentsModule {
    lastValue;
  
    public constructor (m: MediaMarshaller) {
        // hack until resolve: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1201
        // @ts-ignore
        m.subject.subscribe(() => {
            // @ts-ignore
            if (m.activatedBreakpoints.filter((b) => b.alias === 'print').length === 0) {
                // @ts-ignore
                this.lastValue = [...m.activatedBreakpoints];
            } else {
                // @ts-ignore
                m.activatedBreakpoints = [...this.lastValue];
                // @ts-ignore
                m.hook.collectActivations = () => {};
                // @ts-ignore
                m.hook.deactivations = [...this.lastValue];
            }
        });
    }
}
```